# Caching with codeigniter and twig

Tags: codeigniter, caching, twig

I'm trying to cache my output. I'm using Codeigniter's built-in feature $this->output->cache() but it doesn't work. My guess is because I'm using twig. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer, may it be useful for whoever pass here.

```
$output = $this->twig->render('template.html'); // use render instead of display
$this->output->set_output($output); // use CI's output (autoloaded by default) manually
$this->output->cache(5); // cache for 5 minutes, doesn't matter where this line is in the function.
```

Answer (score 1):

As you discovered yourself, you should map output to the `Output` class via one of the appropriate methods in order to take advantage of its built-in caching features. Note that CI 3.0 currently in development on Github has some updates that you may like (gzipped cache files that retain all output headers, for example).

You could extend the `Loader` library with a customized `view()` method, and perform the logic there as well, rather than needing 2+ lines in each controller (if you wanted to load multiple files, you'd have to call `render()` then `append_output()` every time).

[I did exactly that](https://github.com/cryode/CodeIgniter_Smarty) with the Smarty template library. Should be able to do something similar with Twig. (I've been meaning to port it over as well, but haven't had the time.)